# custom titanium module not doing proper work with using xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, titanium

i have created a iphone module later on. it's work on xcode 3 and titanium 1.6.2 but not proper work on xcode 4 and titanium 1.7.2 giving error that Tiproxy.h and TiModule.h file not found pls solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

i experiences something same. building the application with an older titanium sdk version (1.5.x) worked.